# Windows 7 installation on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, hard-drive

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Laptop and assigned whole HDD space to ubuntu. Now i want to reinstall Windows 7 OS back on my PC and want to remove Ubuntu completely.

I have tried to make bootable USB but in BIOS its not supporting as it is in NTFS and my HDD is ext4 format.(I have Windows CD too but unable to mount in ubuntu)

Please help me how to install Windows 7 back.

Open for any mistake done by me and suggestion too!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. On a Windows PC use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) to create a Windows 7 USB installer.
2. Change boot order in BIOS, boot from the USB stick, *delete all existing ext4 partitions* and install the OS.

Edit: Just saw that you have a Windows 7 DVD already. Why are you mounting it in Ubuntu? Just boot from the disc and follow the instructions from step 2 above.

Comment: DVD is not showing in BIOS

Comment: You mean your DVD drive is not showing up in the BIOS and you can't set it as your first boot device? Use a USB stick in that case and get your DVD drive looked at later.

Comment: Thanks for you reply but i tried with USB stick and set it as boot device but then also it not reading.. the reason what i am thinking is that USB is in NTFS system and my machine is installed with UBUNTU (different FS). can this be an issue?

Comment: No, the file system on your HDD doesn't matter. Booting from the USB stick is independent of that or else no-one will be able to remove Linux and install Windows or vice versa. What did you create the USB installer with? Use Rufus as recommended and it should work, otherwise you have other problems with your system.

Comment: then after setting boot from USB its not working...at end ubuntu 14.04 starts.. is there can be other problem?

Comment: Again, what did you create the USB installer with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24369/discussion-between-pulse-and-karan).